# column delimiter in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to import this table in pandas:

[image: Excel Table to import]

When I import it this is what I got:
[image: my code and results]

What should I write in the delimiter parameter so that it keeps the column separated as they are on excel? I have read that by default pandas use commas as separators and that explains why I got these results, but I don't understand what command should I use so that it simply uses the same column separation that excel uses.

Answer (score 0):

You simply specify `;` as separator:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: It was easier than expected.. thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: You're welcome! The problem is that panda's default separator is `,`, but the comma is your separator for decimals.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSV file is using semicolons (`;`) instead of commas (`,`) to delineate cells. In that case, simply add `delimiter=';'` to your `read_csv` call:

```
df = pd.read_csv(`cost10.csv`, header=None, names=column_names, delimiter=';')
```